# Do non-diagonalizable matrices with same eigenvectors commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices with the same set of eigenvectors, they are not supposed to be diagonalizable, how can I prove that $AB=BA$?

I guess this could be proved using some similitude argument, for example Jordan form. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: (didn't realize the comment didnt send earlier) your statement is not true.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Consider the two matrices 
$$
A=\pmatrix{
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
}
,
B=\pmatrix{
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
}.
$$
Both have eigenvectors $e_1$ and $e_4$, but do not commute, as
$$
ABe_3 = 0 \ne  BAe_3=e_1.
$$
Their Jordan forms are different: the blocks have size $(3,1)$ for $A$, but $(2,2)$ for $B$.

---

If we assume that $A$, $B$ are $2\times 2$, upper triangular, and not diagonalizable, then $A$ and $B$ commute. This is no longer true for $3\times 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: No, the set of upper triangular matrices is not commutative, for $n>1$.

Comment: @daw really ? What make you think that ?

Comment: @daw \begin{align} A &= \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix} \\ B &= \begin{bmatrix}d&e\\0&f\end{bmatrix} \\ AB &= \begin{bmatrix}a d&a e + b f\\0&c f\end{bmatrix} \\ BA &= \begin{bmatrix}a d&b d + c e\\0&c f\end{bmatrix} \\ \therefore AB &\ne BA \end{align}

Comment: The OP did not require non-diagonalizability.  He/she permitted non-diagonalizability.  "Not supposed"  and "supposed not"  have different meanings in English.

Comment: @freegoodman I see. I updated my answer to contain those comments.